# How to use the OR [ || ] operator in Cloud Firestore Rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've got these rules for a project I'm making:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /cards/{cardID} {
      allow update: if request.resource.data.size() == 1 &&
      "by" in request.resource.data && 
      request.resource.data.by is number &&
      request.resource.data.by == 1 || request.resource.data.by == -1 &&
      request.resource.data.by != resource.data.by;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm having some trouble to debug or rather I should say understand how the `||` operator works in Cloud Firestore Rules.

This is what all of the above means:

1. `request.resource.data.size() == 1`; gets the number of entries in the map object, it should be 1
2. `"by" in request.resource.data`; the key `"by"` should be in the data object
3. `request.resource.data.by is number`; the value of the `"by"` key should be a number (1 or -1)
4. `request.resource.data.by == 1 || request.resource.data.by == -1`; the value of the `"by"` key in the data object should be 1 or -1 right? (I understand that this value is an integer and not a string)
5. `request.resource.data.by != resource.data.by`; the value of the `"by"` key should not be equal to what's already in the document

What is happening though is that the 4 point in the above list is not getting evaluated as expected, so my guess is that I'm doing something wrong in this line of code since when I remove it all works.

The error I'm getting in the client:

```
"FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions."
```

The call to update the `"by"` field in the database:

```
async updateCount() {
  let count = // it can be 1 or -1
  const res = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .doc("cards/UzSgU6Y5sDvERqnG3gK7")
    .update({
       by: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(count)
    });
},
```

Answer (score 2):

In security rules, `request.resource.data.by` is not going to be the delta by which the client app wants to change to the value.  It's going to be the actual value that will be committed due to the increment.

What you should do instead is compare `request.resource.data.by` (the requested value) with `resource.data.by` (the existing value) to determine if the change between the new and prior values is acceptable.

Comment: You mean that `request.resource.data.by` it's the already computed value? e.g. if what's in the database is `{ by: 1 }` it means that `request.resource.data.by == 0` at the time of execution when I increment by -1 and the other way around?

Comment: Yes, as I said, "It's going to be the actual value that will be committed due to the increment."